# repair SD-card after Marshmallow

Tags: sd-card, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

everyone

I used the feature in Android Marshmallow, format SD card as internal, and I have 3 devices all the same feature available.

after a while I made a factory reset for the devices, and the SD card is not supported and can't be formatted in android device.

I tried using the diskpart in windows, and after "create partition primary" it shows "virtual disk service error the operation is not supported on a non-empty removable disk".

I tried using MiniTool Partition Wizard, but it shows bad disk and after re-inserting the SD card shown nothing was done.

disk management in windows with no use.

what I understood that the android feature make two partitions, 16MB partition and another one for the rest storage which only readable within the android device made it (encrypted some how).

Comment: Have you tried "Cleaning" or deleting the partition in diskpart before creating a primary partition?

Comment: yes I tried clean and delete partition and all show successful but when I try the next order "create partition primary" it shows "virtual disk service error the operation is not supported on a non-empty removable disk"

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it. 
https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_windows/index.html
It is the official reformat tool of the people who design sd card standards. I had to do this with my own 200gb sd card that was seen as 16mb after using as internal storage for a phone.